# Mysql : show 0 and transaction type when no result found

Tags: php, mysql

**Table structure:**

```
reference|transaction|member|summary|amount|action_by|created_at(unix timestamp)
```

My current Sql is :

```
select COALESCE(sum(`amount`) , 0) as `amount` , `transaction`
from `transactions` 
where 
    `transaction` IN ('payment', 'deposit', 'withdraw') and 
    `created_at` >= unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY))
group by transaction
```

Let's say there are no records found for payment.
I still want to get it on the result.
Right now the current result is:

```
100 | deposit 
200 | withdraw
```

What result i need is  :

```
100 | deposit
200 | withdraw
0   | payment
```

I tried several things but I couldn't produce the desired result.
Please help, i'm beginner in sql. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is there a laravel tag

Comment: Why do you need it to be in SQL? Could you achieve the desired result in PHP as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need have a separate table with each unique `transaction` value. This can be done either with a separate table or you can use a derived table as below:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(`amount`),0) as amount, der.transaction_type
FROM (SELECT 'payment' as transaction_type
UNION SELECT 'deposit'
UNION SELECT 'withdraw') der
LEFT JOIN `transactions` t on t.transaction=der.transaction_type AND `transaction` AND `created_at` >= unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY))
group by der.transaction_type
```

This will be show but if your table doesn't have a lot of rows in it then it shouldn't be too big of a deal. It'll perform MUCH better if you have a dedicated table and indexes on the columns